# Xcode unable to load revisions when trying to commit and / or push

Tags: xcode, git, commit

I am currently working on an Xcode project. Lately whenever I try to commit (directly from Xcode), I am not able to do so. 'Unable to load revisions' is displayed in the file list windows.

In addition, I am also not able to push online.

I tried committing and pushing using command line, but either I am not doing it well, or it is simply a band aid solution.

I also tried changing ownership of the xcowrkspace file ( I realm recently) and it does not do anything.

Comment: Personally, I don't know why everybody doesn't just use the git command line ;)  Seriously though: try command line `git status` (to check whether there's stuff ready for commital) and/or `git fetch --dry-run` (to check remote status).  If nothing else, you might get some meaningful error messages that XCode doesn't seem to be giving you.  ALSO: when you *do* finally get meaningful error msgs - *PLEASE* copy/paste them into your post.  Without a good error msg ... we can't help much :(

Comment: As a suggestion, I would not use git from inside Xcode. It's much easier to utilize it either via the command line interface or via a GUI like SourceTree or Tower. Another suggestion would be to post whatever you're seeing via the command line interface when you attempt to push.

Comment: Whenever I have git problems within Xcode, I also do what @Adrian suggested: I use the SourceTree app to commit my code. After using SourceTree to commit, Xcode is able to "recover" and I can use Xcode to commit to my repository again.